# PHP Curl_exec output is getting trimmed

Tags: php

I am hitting my content server which sends  multipart data.

When server response is small ( < 40KB ) , I am getting full response data in **$response**
string. But when server response data is large ( > 112KB) its getting trimmed to 48KB
and my whole multipart data parsing is failing.

What should I do to get the whole 112KB data in $response string ?

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
);

$ch = curl_init( $this->url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arr_param);



$response = curl_exec( $ch );

$err     = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );

parseData($response);
```

Please help, what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but why don't you use `$options` after initializing it?